# What basic language and documents I have to learn for Testing Automation ? I don't have experience in any language and I am in Manual testing

Tags: automated-testing, manual-testing, languages

I dont have any coding experience and right now i am in the field of Manual testing , I have to learn Testing Automation . Now what basics for which language i have to start working on?

Comment: This is a very broad question. It's like asking how do I test. There are a lot of such questions on SQA. Please explore them first.

Comment: Python is widely considered best language for beginners, and has plenty of free learning resources and good Selenium bindings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@nikzz_0402
You need to look within the company what kind of project they have. Also ask developers view on it- what kind of automation they want for project. More then that consider Mike Cohn automation pyramid

[image]
Now according to project you can investigate automation possibilities, tools and you also get to know what programming languages you need to learn.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should start to learn programming language JAVA if you are thinking to move for web application automation testing.

For functional automation testing Selenium webdriver is best to start , Please have a look with following for more details :

1 - [Download Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/)

2 - [Selenium & Java tutorials](http://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/selenium-tutorial-selenium-webdriver-tutorials/)

Selenium supports many other programming languages like Python, Perl, Ruby, php, c#. so you can start to learn any of these to work in automation testing. Java is just my suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

This is depends on What your company is doing / Where you are going to use Test Automation . If you are planning to use The test automation at work , it would be wise to learn the technologies your company planned to use . If this is for you own  I would like to suggest below

01) [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) - For Web Automation

02) [Test Stack White](https://github.com/TestStack/White) - For Windows Desktop Application Automation

03) Appium - For Mobile Testing

All these 3 technologies are Free and Generic so that can be used for creating any advance testing framework also good for learning compared to Easy-to-use tools . 02) Technology Requires knowledge in c# , and both Selenium and Appium can be use with c# . So if you are planning to Test Stack White as well   Learning C# would be ideal . Otherwise Java also a good choice

Comment: My company working on PHP language only so is it ok? , that I learn JAVA or C# for automation . i dont have idea how this 2 language integrate with each other !!

Comment: If you've read about black box testing,  we don't need to interact with the inlying code.  So it doesn't matter whether the company works on PHP,  Java,  Ruby.

Comment: Theoretically Black Box testing does not depends on the technologies what applications written with . But for practical reasons Test Automation usually follow same technology stacks company uses . As an example if a company build their applications with   Open source technologies it may not have windows , visual studio license and CI will be much easier if automation follows same technology stack . Choosing Java or C# can be done as per the requirement

Answer (score 0):

Web test automation: Sahi 
* Don't need to have programming language knowledge in depths.
* Use only java-scripts language( can do with Java also).

On negative side, its bit tricky on setting up.
So if you need help on this can provide.

Desktop application: AutoIT

This is great tool but its complex in scripting.

............
Thanks
Dev